# Термин игровой движок в официальных документах

Tags: документация, движок

Собственно в этом и вопрос. Пишу диплом по созданию игрового движка. Тема: "программной средство создания кроссплатформенных игровых приложений". т.е. по сути это и есть игровой движок, но не будешь же в тексте всегда называть его таким длинным определением.

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Можно ли употреблять понятие «игровой движок»? Думаю, да. Можно сделать как-то так: «программное средство создания кроссплатформенных игровых приложений (*далее — игровой движок*)».

Comment: В глоссарии его укажите, если сомневаетесь. Термин очень даже общепринятый.

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы